# Android: why webview doesnt start loading url unless it is visible to user?

Tags: android, webview

My webview (initially invisible) gets url to load:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ...
    webView.loadUrl("some url");
    ...
}
```

Then, in onClickListener I change its visibility to visible and see nothing loaded. If I set visibility to visible and THEN load url, it works ok, but user should wait for some time while url is loading. I want to preload everything and show ALREADY LOADED webpage. How to do it? Webview loads something if only it is visible...

P.S. btw, I tried making the webview visible and setting translationY large enough the view to go below screen - still, it loads nothing unless I invoke setTranslationY(0); ... what to do?

P.P.S. I tried invoking webView.loadData - same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen_web);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.uk");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
}

public void testing (View view){
    mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Button in screen_web.xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="testing"
    android:text="Button" />
```

WebView in screen_web.xml:

```
    <WebView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.32"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

It works well for me.